# How to get multiprocessing to change the state of my original objects?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I think that I understand the problem, when a `multiprocessing.Pool.map` worker grabs it's next assignment, the arguments are passed as a picked object according to the docs. This is fine if the return value is what you are looking for, but what if I want to call a function which changes the state of an object *in parallel*? For example, consider the simple object:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class state():
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = 0
    def __repr__(self): 
        return "%s"%self.z
    def compute(self):
        print "Computing"
        self.z += 1
```

And some manipulations with this object:

```
def compute_function(x): x.compute()

A = [state() for _ in xrange(3)]
print A
A[2].compute()
print A
map(compute_function, A)
print A
P = Pool()
P.map(compute_function, A)
print A
```

The output is:

```
[0, 0, 0]
Computing
[0, 0, 1]
Computing
Computing
Computing
[1, 1, 2]
Computing
Computing
Computing
[1, 1, 2]
```

But I expect to get the last line to read `[2, 2, 3]`. Clearly, `compute` was called, but the resulting object was thrown away. How do I "keep the state"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Pickling doesn't allow you to send back state changes to pickled objects. The simplest thing you can do is:

```
def compute_function(x):
    x.compute()
    return x

A = [state() for _ in xrange(3)]
A = P.map(compute_function, A)
```

As an alternative you can use [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers) which create the object and puts it in a separate process and provide proxies to other processes. Note however that this means that **any** operation on the object through the proxies will do a communication between processes which is *slow*.